# How to install go package after downloading?

Tags: go, go-get, gitleaks

I ran this:

```
cd $GOPATH && go get -u github.com/zricethezav/gitleaks
```

perplexingly, I now have this:

```
$GOPATH/
     src/
       github.com/
         gitleaks/
```

but there is not a `bin/` folder ... I would have expected to see the bin folder here:  `$GOPATH/bin`

did I do something wrong? How do I install the package so that the binary shows up? I tried running:

```
go install github.com/zricethezav/gitleaks
```

but after installing I don't see a `bin/` folder...

The output of `go env` looks like:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/Users/alex/go/bin"
GOCACHE="/Users/alex/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/alex/go"
GOPROXY=""
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/st/159q4vsd64b69_x99dtzzt6m0000gn/T/go-build133179815=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

Comment: Do you have `GOBIN` set? Did you try with `-v` or `-x` to see what the output is? `github.com/gitleaks/` != `github.com/zricethezav/gitleaks`, so I'm not sure how you go the former.

Comment: It looks like your `go install` package name has an extraneous prefix, `src/`.  Keep in mind that `$GOPATH/src` is the directory where package source is stored.  The actual package names are the parts of the pathnames that proceed `$GOPATH/src`.

Comment: yeah I just posted a half-answer, maybe that helps

Answer (score 0):

After `go get`, the gitleaks executable should be in `$GO_PATH\bin` directory, not in the `$GO_PATH\src...\gitleaks`.

See this: https://pocketgophers.com/go-install-vs-go-build/

Answer (score 0):

I installed golang on MacOS with `brew install go`, and that apparently didn't put the main binaries in `/usr/local/go`, which is why my `go get` command failed.

so instead of using brew, I installed via: https://golang.org/doc/install?download=go1.12.5.darwin-amd64.pkg

and after installing using the .pkg file, there were files in `/usr/local/go`, so then my `go get` command worked.

My guess is that homebrew puts the go binaries in a different location than `/usr/local/go` which kinda sux but I could see why.

Answer (score -1):

If $GOPATH isn't go's root directory I think you have to create bin folder manually. I've manually created $GOPATH/bin folder and its working fine.

Comment: GOPATH should never be go’s root directory. It will produce an error if it is.